# how to create objects with different names within a loop using python?

Tags: python, loops, object

Either the answer to that question will work, or I've read that you don't need to actually name them... so i tried this:

```
class Entry():
    __slots__ = ('name', 'gender', 'occurances')

def mkEntry(name_foo, gender_foo, occurances_foo):
    myEntry = Entry
    myEntry.name = name_foo
    myEntry.gender = gender_foo
    myEntry.occurances = occurances_foo
    return myEntry

def topTwenty(fileName):
    file = open(fileName)
    topTwenty = []
    femaleCount = 0
    maleCount = 0
    for line in file:
        a = line.split(",")
        if a[1] == 'F' and femaleCount < 20:
            topTwenty.append(mkEntry(a[0], a[1], a[2]))
            femaleCount = femaleCount + 1
    print(topTwenty[7].name)
```

but the print(topTwenty[7].name) is printing what i expect from topTwenty[20].name

any help?

Comment: [Lots of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D__slots__+%3D+%28%27name%27%2C+%27gender%27%2C+%27occurances%27%29) on this topic showing up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `myEntry = Entry()` to create an instance of the class.  Right now you are just overwriting the attributes of the same class every time, and appending that same class to the list every time.  Your list just contains the same item 20 times.

This is a weird way to do things anyway.  Why don't you move that code from `mkEntry` into an `__init__` on the `Entry` class, to keep the initialization together with the class.

Comment: thank you. and i'm using mkEntry because i'm in an intro to cs class and we haven't learned __init__ yet, so we can't use it yet.